# Remote debugging in eclipse with jetty server

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I configured the debug configurations for remote debugging my maven project. I set the host as localhost and the port as 7000. I even ran the following command as the launch was not working:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=7000,suspend=n
```

However it is still not launching the remote VM and I cannot proceed with my debugging.

It gives the same error as:

> Failed to connect to remote VM.Connection refused.

How should I proceed with solving this problem ?

Comment: You know you have those port numbers different, yes? And you know you need to run the server jvm yourself and then attach the debugger? Might be worth temporarily setting suspend to y to get it to wait for a connection

Comment: I changed it to the following and still it doesn't work .  :(           -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=7000,server=y,suspend=y

Comment: Are you running that command line beginning "java -Xdebug..." in your question? What are you hoping that will do? What does it do? You need to be more specific about what you're doing and what errors you're seeing

Answer (score 1):

you can issue the follwoing command from command prompt. mvnDebug jetty:run-exploded antrun:run Then you wil come to know on which port your jetty is listening to after that go to run->debug configuration from there you can debug your server.
In debug configuration you can find the option Remote Java Application here create one new debug configuration for new Remote java Application and also here you can define your new server
again **mvnDebug jetty:run-exploded**  now you should see your new port.